# Why won't my bootstrap collapse function work after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm writing a small page with forms for network settings. There is a toggle to switch between DHCP and static modes. When in DHCP mode, a JS function runs to collapse the div containing the inputs for IP and Subnet Mask. However, after a page refresh, the collapse function doesn't work fully. I can see the function is called as the IP and subnet fields disable in the same function, it's just the collapse which fails.

The collapse will begin to work again if I first press the Static option (which shows the fields again).

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Control Panel</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form> 



    <label class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">Network Mode</label>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary" onchange="disableStatic()">
        <input type="radio" name="networkMode" id="DHCP"  autocomplete="off" value="0">DHCP
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary" onchange="enableStatic()">
        <input type="radio" name="networkMode" id="static" autocomplete="off" value="1" checked>Static
      </label>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="ip-subnet-params">


    <label for="ip1" class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">IP Address</label>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" maxLength="3" class="form-control" id="ip1" placeholder="IP_1" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
       <input type="number" min="0" max="255" maxLength="3" class="form-control" id="ip2" placeholder="IP_2" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" maxLength="3" class="form-control" id="ip3" placeholder="IP_3" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" maxLength="3" class="form-control" id="ip4" placeholder="IP_4" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <label for="sub1" class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">Subnet Mask</label>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" maxLength="3" class="form-control" id="sub1" placeholder="Subnet_1" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" maxLength="3" class="form-control" id="sub2" placeholder="Subnet_2" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" maxLength="3" class="form-control" id="sub3" placeholder="Subnet_3" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" maxLength="3" class="form-control" id="sub4" placeholder="Subnet_4" oninput="javascript: if(this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>


      <br>

      <label for="mac1" class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">MAC Address</label>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text" maxLength="2" pattern="^[^g-zG-Z]{2}$" class="form-control" id="mac1" placeholder="MAC_1">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text"maxLength="2" pattern="^[^g-zG-Z]{2}$" class="form-control" id="mac2" placeholder="MAC_2">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text"maxLength="2" pattern="^[^g-zG-Z]{2}$" class="form-control" id="mac3" placeholder="MAC_3">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text"maxLength="2" pattern="^[^g-zG-Z]{2}$" class="form-control" id="mac4" placeholder="MAC_4">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text"maxLength="2" pattern="^[^g-zG-Z]{2}$" class="form-control" id="mac5" placeholder="MAC_5">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="text"maxLength="2" pattern="^[^g-zG-Z]{2}$" class="form-control" id="mac6" placeholder="MAC_6">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Submit</button>
  </form>


  <script>

    function disableStatic() {
        document.getElementById("ip1").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("ip2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("ip3").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("ip4").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("sub1").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("sub2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("sub3").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("sub4").disabled = true;
        $('.ip-subnet-params').collapse('hide');


      }

      function enableStatic() {
        document.getElementById("ip1").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("ip2").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("ip3").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("ip4").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("sub1").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("sub2").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("sub3").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("sub4").disabled = false;
        $('.ip-subnet-params').collapse('show');
      }
  </script>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the page to load with all fields shown, and for the IP and Subnet fields to be collapsed when I press the DHCP button.

What actually happens is when you press DHCP, the Ip and subnet fields disable but don't collapse. After pressing the Static button, the collapse on DHCP button press works fine again.

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: Apologies, post edited with minimum reproducible example. Thanks

Comment: Use `<div class="ip-subnet-params collapse show">` (calling `hide()` won't work if the element isn't properly classed, `show()` will add the missing classes though, which is why hiding will start working eventually) https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2n1046yz/

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!

Comment: You can try out the Bootstrap Js Collapse (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp)